# Load the python dictionary from csv file

Tags: python

I saved the dictionary `dict` `dict_keys(['df1', 'df2'])` into a `csv` file. `cat data.csv` outputs something like this?

```
,,df1,df2
quantile_10,h0,0.03636844456195831,0.105098
quantile_10,h5,0.0654495671391487,0.108322
quantile_10,h10,0.10933497846126557,0.113496
quantile_10,h15,0.1400846481323242,0.119098
quantile_10,h20,0.1513956755399704,0.068324
quantile_10,h25,0.11640003025531769,0.017974
quantile_10,h30,0.026758757233619694,9.4e-05
quantile_10,h35,0.0020915842149406673,0.0
quantile_20,h0,0.05211468040943147,0.130436
quantile_20,h5,0.08270514607429505,0.125416
quantile_20,h10,0.12569279968738556,0.125436
quantile_20,h15,0.14520362317562102,0.149596
```

How to open this dictionary in python so I have a `dict['df1']`, `dict['df2']` and quantiles being row indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pandas library to read this CSV file and reconstruct the original dictionary.

- Read the csv with the first two columns set as the index
- Convert the DataFrame to a dictionary where keys are column names (`df1`, `df2`, etc.) and values are DataFrames with the multi-index intact.

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the CSV with the first two columns as index
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=[0, 1])

# Extract each 'df' as a transposed DataFrame and store in a dictionary
data_dict = {col: df[[col]].unstack().T for col in df.columns}

# Access the data
print(data_dict['df1'].columns)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Yuri R. What I want to achieve is `df1.columns Index(['h0', 'h5', 'h10', 'h15', 'h20', 'h25', 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype='object')`. With your suggestion i have `df1.columns` `Index(['beam0110_df'], dtype='object')`

Comment: Got it. I updated my codebase